# Deleting particular files in a folder

Tags: php, mysql, directory

I have a database table with name of **Added_images**. My table contains a list of image names such as **image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg, etc**.

I have a folder named **images**. It contains all uploaded images such as **image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg,image-4.jpg, image-5.jpg**, and **image-6.jpg**.

I want to check every picture in the folder images against the table Added_images.  If the picture is in the table, I would like to keep it. Otherwise I would like to delete it. How can i achieve this?

Comment: do you mean delete all files inside of images/ if it isnt in the table?

Comment: the images like image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg are into mysql table. so these images should not be deleted. the others(image-4.jpg, image-5.jpg, image-6.jpg) should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `scandir` or `glob` (or something else) to obtain an array containing all the files in your directory.
2. Loop over the list of images, deleting filenames not listed in the database.

Something like:

```
$files = glob('Added_images/image-*.jpg');
$databaseFiles = getListOfFilesFromDatabase();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $databaseFiles)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

You should obviously test this carefully before use in case it deletes images it shouldn't...

**Edit:**

Thinking harder you could probably express this more cleanly like this:

```
$files = glob('Added_images/image-*.jpg');
$databaseFiles = getListOfFilesFromDatabase();

$filesToDelete = array_diff($files, $databaseFiles);
array_map('unlink', $filesToDelete);
```

Comment: i checked your codes. it displays errors like Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #2 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\php\my_folder\delete.php on line 29

Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in C:\wamp\www\php\my_folder\delete.php on line 30

Comment: Did you implement a function called `getListOfFilesFromDatabase()` which returns an array containing the list of files from the database?